# Raw POST from Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do a raw POST to an internal page from a unit test, and for some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<String:0x258a910>
    unit/call_route_attempt_test.rb:10:in `test_response_from_call_info'
```

My code looks like this:

```
post :call_info, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request-call-info>...SOME XML HERE...</request-call-info>'
```

That should be fine according to the API docs. The only format I can get to work is if I send it as parameters like so:

```
post :call_info, :post => {:a_var => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request-call-info>...SOME XML HERE...</request-call-info>'}
```

I have a feeling I need to require some part of the library that for some reason isn't working here.

**Edit**
As user Sarah Mei points out, I'm calling the wrong post method. I think it has to do with my class inheritance, which I'm not sure I can change given the circumstances of me running a test. The class definition is as follows:

```
class anApiControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
```

The method I'm *trying* to implement is the **post (ActiveResource::Connection)** method listed on the Rails API docs. I'm really new to this, quite lost and on a deadline. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which `post` method you're calling. There's one in [ActionController::Integration::Session](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Integration/Session/post), one in [ActionController::TestProcess](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestProcess/post), one in [ActiveResource::Connection](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Connection/post)...etc. Most of them take a params hash as the second parameter, so if the second call works, you're probably not calling the `post` you think you're calling.

Comment: I think you're definitely right. How do I specify which one to call?